# How to perform check on each object when querying in django? 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'has_group_permission'

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have this property which I will use to return all users with a given permission:

```
@property
def assignable(self):
    return User.objects.all().has_group_permission('help_desk', 'ticket', 'view', self.group)
```

However, when used the following is returned:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'has_group_permission'
```

In theory, I'm using the function has_group_permission on every object returned from User.objects.all() and checking if it has the required permission. But this obviously doesn't work. What solutions are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User.objects.all() returns a queryset. You will need to loop over the queryset and compile a list of the users. Also, if this is a property on a model I'm not sure you can return a list.

```
valid_users = []

for user in User.objects.all():
  if user.has_group_permission('help_desk', 'ticket', 'view', self.group):
    valid_users.append(user)
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case